# How do I find orthogonal vectors using the del operator in an arbitrary coordinate system?

Tags: calculus, vectors, vector-fields, divergence-operator, curl

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YHPa5.png)

The image shows the full question, part (b) is what I'm interested in.

I'm stuck on how to use the del operator here to find out if $\vec{B}_0$, $\vec{E}_0$ and $\vec{q}$ are orthogonal. I tried using the cross prduct, but since there are no coordinate systems used in the definition of $\vec{B}$ and $\vec{E}$, it doesn't seem to give me anything useful.

Any advice?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: $\overrightarrow{E}_0$ orthogonal to $\overrightarrow{q}$ follows from $\nabla\cdot \overrightarrow{E}=0$. To establish that $\overrightarrow{B}_0$ and $\overrightarrow{E}_0$ orthogonal you could perhaps use one of these relations https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_algebra_relations.

Comment: *there are no coordinate systems used in the definition of $\vec{B}$ and $\vec{E}$* That’s not true. The position vector $\mathbf r$ is $(x,y,z)$ in Cartesian coordinates.